# Using DataTables extension KeyTables for rows instead of cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm currently building a webpage with Bootstrap 4 beta/JQuery and [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) with the extentions Select and KeyTables. KeyTable allows to navigate with arrow keys through all cells. I want to just navigate through whole rows. So is it possible to convert the keytable cell navigation to row navigation?

Here is an [Example](https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html) from the default cell navigation from KeyTables with Bootstrap 4

Comment: Conciseness and clarity

Answer (score 2):

#### SOLUTION

This could be done by limiting keys that KeyTable plug-in listens for and handling cell focus/blur event generated by KeyTable.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
    keys: {
       keys: [ 13 /* ENTER */, 38 /* UP */, 40 /* DOWN */ ]
    }
});

// Handle event when cell gains focus
$('#example').on('key-focus.dt', function(e, datatable, cell){
    // Select highlighted row
    $(table.row(cell.index().row).node()).addClass('selected');
});

// Handle event when cell looses focus
$('#example').on('key-blur.dt', function(e, datatable, cell){
    // Deselect highlighted row
    $(table.row(cell.index().row).node()).removeClass('selected');
});

// Handle key event that hasn't been handled by KeyTable
$('#example').on('key.dt', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){
    // If ENTER key is pressed
    if(key === 13){
        // Get highlighted row data
        var data = table.row(cell.index().row).data();

        // FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY
        $("#example-console").html(data.join(', '));
    }
});
```

Extra CSS rules are needed to hide cell highlighting used by KeyTable plug-in.

#### DEMO

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/rbhhmqpw/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: How to navigate rows with KeyTable plug-in](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-navigate-rows-with-keytable-plugin/) for more examples and details.